# 2004 Kawasaki Vulcan 1500 Classic Parking lights and brake lights aren't working

Tags: motorcycle, ignition, lights, kawasaki, vulcan

2004 Kawasaki Vulcan 1500 Classic Parking lights and brake lights aren't working.

Parking lights work with the ignition switch in parking light position but not in run! It will start and run. I'm thinking bad ignition switch???

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!